# scrollview size not set to the size defined in the storyboard

Tags: ios, layout, swift3, scrollview

I am trying to embed a scrollview inside a view controller shown in the image below. I constrain the scrollview to fill the entire superview (which is View here) as shown in the image below. However, when this scrollView is actually instantiated when segueing to it it's actual size is not same as the size of superview. IN particular, the size of the superview is (414, 736) but the size of the scrollview is (375, 667). You can see the printed statement in the picture which shows the size of the superview (View) and the scrollview. 
I eventually want to auto zoom the embedded image in the scrollview so that it fits the width of the scrollview. I'm not sure what's going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a swift newbie.

[image]

Comment: try to add subview to scrollview and give width constraint and required all constraints and check.

Answer (score 0):

currently ,i thing you've some confuse between (width , height) of frame & (width height) of screen size , this issue you facing will resolve when you log :

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

print("screenWidth : \(screenWidth) & screenHeight : \(screenHeight)")
```

&

```
print("frame Width : \(view.frame.size.width) &  frame Height : \\(view.frame.size.height)")
```

i hope this help

Comment: they are of same size. how is that supposed to resolve my issue?

Comment: you can try set contentSize (property of ScollView ) for your ImageView ,

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck Resize View From Nib.

[image]

Comment: I unchecked "Resize View from NIB" for the view controller but that didn't work. But I'm curious what that was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Print log in ViewDidAppear**

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(scrollview.frame)

    }
```

**Another Way and check frame**

1. Disable autolayout .
2. Give AutoResizing as below :

[image]

Comment: Okay, I'll try that right now. However, even if I print the frame size of scrollView before setting its contentView, I get the same (375, 667) size.

Comment: ok try this and let me know ...and another way try to disable autolayout and check again.

Comment: So I dragged a container view inside inside the scroll view and constrained it to be the same size as the scrollView. However, that didn't make any different in the size of the scrollView's frame. What's weird is that although scrollView's width is smaller that the full width of the UIWindow, it is able to display the full width of UIImage subview which has same width as the UIWindow width.

Comment: wait i add screenshot to answer .

Comment: So I was using the story board of iphone7 but the emulator was iphone7plus. That's why the size of the view's frame was changing from iphone7's size to iphone7plus size when I segue to the viewController that contains the scrollView. However, surprisingly the frame size of the scrollView is same as the size of the storyboard. I tried to make the storyboard iphone version same as the emulator and it solved the problem without using container. However, this raises another issue that how to I fit the screen of any iphone version but use the storyboard of only one of the version.

Comment: or try to print log n viewdidAppear it is easy solution without any above steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145595/discussion-between-suraj-keshri-and-kkrocks).